# Azure service bus alert notifications at topic level

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-alerts

I am working on a request to create topic level alert for Azure Service Bus but unable to add such filters.
Addition to this I couldn't find any alert creation option available under Topic details.

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Navigate to your Service Bus namespace in the Azure portal.
Under "Monitoring" > "Alerts", create a new alert rule.
Select appropriate metrics like "Active Messages", "Dead-lettered Messages", or "Server Errors".

Comment: Thanks for acknowledgment but above alert will apply to all topics not to a selected one. So is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Alerts enable you to proactively monitor and manage your Azure resources by notifying you when certain conditions are met. These conditions are specified using alert rules, and when triggered, alerts can initiate actions to address or investigate [issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-overview).

- Navigate to your Service Bus namespace in the Azure portal. Under "Monitoring" > "Alerts", create a new alert rule. Select appropriate metrics like "Active Messages", "Dead-lettered Messages", or "Server Errors".
- For the selected one, choose `Split by dimensions` and select `Dimension Name` as `EntityName` and `Dimension values` as `AzureServiceBusTopicName`.
- Select the operator used to compare the metric value against the threshold and enter a threshold number.
- If required, select action groups or create an action group.
  [image]
- If required, select action groups or create an action group. I have selected the action group "mail" in the Actions tab.
  [image]
  Ensure to fill in the Alert rule details in the details tab, such as:
- The severity of the alert when the rule's condition is met,
- Choose a name to identify this alert rule, and
- Add a description for this alert rule .

[image]

- It providing timely notifications and actions based on defined conditions

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sam for your response and its working as expected.